# How can I fix a for loop that checks dictionary values?

Tags: regex, loops, dictionary, for-loop, julia

I know it may sound like a newbie question, but i'm having a hard time trying to make a loop work.

I'm using Julia language to create a simple regular expressions that checks if a telephone number is valid and return the estate of the number according to the code area. Here are the details:

*1-User enters the phone number;*

*2-Regex tests if it's a valid number;*

*3-The area code is parsed and checked if present in the dictionary values. If yes, then it should return the key owning that value. Otherwise a simple message saying that area code doesn't exist should be printed.*

The problem is: the loop goes for as long as possible, printing if the value is available or not everytime it checks for it in the dictionary. A break wouldn't help much: as soon as it got the first check, it would simply stop.

Then ofc I noticed I had to take the final print statement out of the loop and even maybe assign a variable to get the value copied, but it still overwrites with the very last "Number doesn't exist" result.

How can I rewrite this code so it works?

```
regexTel = r"^(\+55)?[\s]?\(?(\d{2})?\)?[\s-]?(9?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4})$"
areaCode = Dict("City A"=> [68],
            "City B"=> [82], [...] (and so on)

print("Type the phone number:\n")
telNum = readline()
validTel = (match(regexTel, telNum))
fnlAreaCd = parse(Int32, validTel[2])

for (cityCode, availbCode) in areaCode
    if fnlAreaCd in availbCode
        println("Phone number: ", validTel[3], "\n",
        "Area code: ", fnlAreaCd, "\n",
        "City: ", cityCode)
    else 
        println("Area code doesn't exist")
    end
end
```

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but I would not use a regex here. Because it means that if the user input the correct digits but the wrong separators, you won't recognise the telephone number although the user keyed the numbers correctly. Instead, I would keep only the digits and check there are 10 of them.

Answer (score 3):

Your usage of `Dict` seems strange to me. I think you should use it the other way around.

I believe that the area codes are unique, then the varaible `areaCode` would be like this:

```
areaCode = Dict(68 => "City A", 82 => "City B", ...) # do you need to wrap them in an array?
```

It'll allow you to write much simplier code:

```
if haskey(areaCode, fnlAreaCd)
    cityCode = areaCode[fnlAreaCd]
    println("Phone number: ", validTel[3], "\n",
            "Area code: ", fnlAreaCd, "\n",
            "City: ", cityCode)
else 
    println("Area code doesn't exist")
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatell,y I can't do what you stated because there are estates here with multiple area codes, so I do have to set it Estate A => [51,52,53,54,59 etc.]

Comment: You could add additional entries to the `Dict`, if each estate can have multiple area codes but not vice versa

Answer (score 1):

The matching city won't necessarily be the first entry in the dictionary, but you have instructed the code to say it doesn't exist any time it finds a non-match! Try this instead of your bare loop:

```
function lookup_areacode(acode)
    code_exists = false
    for (cityCode, availbCode) in areaCode
        if acode in availbCode
            code_exists = true
            println("Phone number: ", tel, "\n",
            "Area code: ", acode, "\n",
            "City: ", cityCode)
        end
    end

    if !code_exists  
        println("Area code doesn't exist")
    end
end

lookup_areacode(fnlAreaCd)
```

You may want to move the dictionary inside the function for neatness.

Comment: Never use boolean variable with comparison operator. Instead of `if code_exists == false` it should be `if !code_exists`. It's cleaner and faster. Or, even better, use shortcuts `code_exists || println("Area code doesn't exist")`.

Comment: Thanks! Old habits die hard. Updated the text.